# ELKI Outlier detection on 1D data

Tags: vector, cluster-analysis, local, outliers, elki

I have been trying to get LOF on a 1D data based on Eucledian distance. But I keep getting "Could not evaluate outlier results, as I could not find a minority label." Error. Please see below. The data looks like this:

`0.366959
0.134065
0.54
0.292419
0.449071
0.42
0.208460
0.336666`

Here is the command I give:

```
 -dbc.in C:\Users\...\Adata.txt -algorithm clustering.em.EM,outlier.lof.LOF -em.k 3 -lof.k 3
```

Clustering is done correctly but it fails on outlier detection. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an error, but a warning.

ELKI tries to automatically *evaluate*, but can only do so if it has labeled data.

Try writing the output to a file. It probably worked, and you just didn't notice because it doesn't have a nice scatter plot visualization for 1D data.

```
-resulthandler ResultWriter -out someFolder
```

Comment: Hey! thanks. Yes, now I see the outlier scores in the file lof-outlier_order.txt. How can I see it as those nice scatter plots with outliers circled?

Comment: OK, I get it now. ELKI needs another column to draw a scatter plot. I gave the indices of the observation points as column 0 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: These circle plots really only make *sense* for multivariate data. Do *not* add the indices as column 0! This changes the result, and the indices are probably *not meaningful* to use in the distance computations! As a hack, you could duplicate the column that you have; but then obviously all points will be on the diagonal line.